# Display name and/or path of currently viewed email in mutt/neomutt

Tags: linux, command-line, email, mutt, maildir

I'm using [`neomutt`](https://neomutt.org) (an updated fork of [`mutt`](http://www.mutt.org)) as my CLI MUA (read: mail reading software in the terminal) and have all my messages synced offline using [`isync`/`mbsync`](https://isync.sourceforge.io/) and stored in the `maildir`-format on my `Debian Stable` system.

Sometimes I want to reply to a message and attach another email (e.g. as a reference).  This can be easily done when using the `maildir`-storage format since all messages are separate files; I just need to attach the file in my local folder.  The problem is that I have difficulties finding the email files.

Obviously I can search through all of my messages (e.g. by using [`mu`](https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/), which is my mail indexer) and then attach it, but this is tedious. It would be a lot easier to just display the path and filename somewhere when I read an email, optimally in my pager within `neomutt`.

But despite looking for a solution, I wasn't able to find that.  Any ideas or workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just stumbled onto a solution: before sending the email, instead of pressing `a` to attach a file you can use `A` to select a mail folder, then using `t` to tag one (or multiple) messages and then attach the selected messages using `Return`.